# Can cucumber after hook get scenario variables?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

My cucumber scenario is as follows:

```
Scenario: test add user
Given I logged in with email
When I add user with name test1 in my test
Then I should see my user
#After remove user with name test1
```

Some sample step definitions is as:

```
When /^add user with name (\w+) in my test$/ do |name|
    @test.add_user(name)
end
```

I would like to remove the user I just added after the test scenario has finished to keep the system clean. Can I achieve this by using After hook? I cannot find a way to pass the users name into the After hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a way of specifically passing information into hooks, which is a good thing, your scenarios *should* be ignorant of whatever hooks may or may not be executed.

Hooks can get access to global state though, so you could easily add each created user to a global array, and use a hook to clean those users out:

```
# In step def
@test_users ||= []
@test_users << name
@test.add_user(name)

# In hook
@test_users.each { |u| @test.remove_user(u) }
```

It's worth pointing out that the [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem is specifically designed for clearing out test data between tests or test suites, and may be able to provide you with what you want without having to hand-roll your own cleanup code.